# Error with the installation of AWS Toolkit for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin

I can't install the AWS toolkit for Eclipse. 
I can't understand how to download and what is this "bundle org.eclipse.core.variables 3.2.800" and what is the dependency at the end of message?
This is the error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201707121824)
>   Missing requirement: AWS Toolkit Core Plugin 2.3.1.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.3.1.v201707121824) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.variables 3.2.800' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201707121824 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201707121824)
>   To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.core [2.3.1.v201707121824]

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.core.variables` is one of the standard Eclipse plugins. The error message is saying you need to be using a version of Eclipse with at least version 3.2.800 of this plugin.

Version 3.2.800 of this plugin is in Eclipse Luna, so this means you need to be using that release or later (Luna, Mars, Neon, or Oxygen).